# Is writing important for electronic composition?

Tags: composition, electronic-music, songwriting

I am an electronic producer, and I was wondering if electronic music producers even write down their music on scores? Is that important enough to do for this category of music genres? Or should I do despite that others don't?

Comment: It depends on what you are producing and the level of complexity and also the environment you are working in. If you are working in a software DAW, the notes are essentially written down for you. In MIDI you get a grid showing pitch/velocity/duration of every note. For me if it's an especially complex song I might write down a couple notes on structure/form, but not much else.. certainly nothing in standard notation.

Comment: As an electronic musician, I personally prefer using my DAW's score notation feature to the piano roll most of the time. (Of course, I record myself playing a MIDI controller just as frequently...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends.

It's not important, in the sense that it is not needed. There are different input dynamics, you use the one that you are more comfortable with.

It can be important, though. If you are not comfortable with piano rolls, sequencers, or performing the piece, or with any other notation/input system, and you are proficient with score writing, then writing scores will be very important for you!

Just use whatever is more efficient and/or whatever you enjoy the most and/or whatever is needed.

All you'll need is either a DAW with a good score editor, or a good score editor that can translate to MIDI.